# Forwarding REST API requests and responses using iptables

Tags: iptables, routing

I want a linux node that I own to be the 'router' -so to speak- for certain packages, REST API packages to be precise.

The whole situation is this, I have made a web-ui program, this program will be a client (call it node-A) , this client will send REST API requests to a server that I own (call it node-B) , but ... I don't want anyone to know anything about node B, not even the domain name, I don't even want them to know that it exists ... the reason is that it's critical to me, and I haven't reached the stage where I'm comfortable with it's security.

So it came to my mind to use another server that I own as intermediate node (call it node-int) , to forward connections from node-A to node-B .

I want the client node-A to make the REST API requests to node-int which will forward the request to node-B , and receive the response from node-B and forward it back to node-A.

The only problem is: I don't know how exactly to do so with iptables, should I use filter table:FORWARD chain, mangle table for altering the packets themselves, or the nat table?

I don't know what is best for the job, that's why I'm asking here in hope for the more experienced to guide me to the best way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You do not do it with IP tables, you do it with http-server configs.

- Setup two http servers. One visible to the public (your node-int), and another inside your LAN, unaccessible from outside world (your node-B).
- On the public server you enable proxy and define which URLs are processed right here, which goes to the node-B, which goes to some other server.

The exact config statement depends on the http server of course, so here is how it is done on Apache:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Other http servers would have something similar.

Comment: is there **NO WAY** to do it with iptables !?

Comment: With ip tables you will do all or nothing. With IP forwarding, any request which comes to an intermediate server is forwarded to a protected one. Regardless of is it a REST API request or static page or some SOAP request. So if you are talking about REST - you should go with proxy http server. IP forwarding can be useful if your "intermediate" server has several in-LAN servers separated by port on the intermediate. Possible, but it is a different level - the one where any talks about REST loose its meaning.